# Why doesn't the Clojure Compiler throw an error for an incorrect type hint?

Tags: clojure, compiler-errors, compiler-optimization, type-hinting

**Assumptions:**

- I get that type hints are about performance optimisations, and not type checking. I'm trying to work out when a performance optimisation is ineffective.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
(ns test.core)

(defrecord SquarePeg [width length])
(defrecord RoundHole [radius])

(def square-peg (SquarePeg. 5 50))

(defn insert-peg [^test.core.RoundHole peg]
  (println "insert-peg inserted with: " peg))

(defn -main
  "Insert a square peg in a round hole"
  [& args]
  (insert-peg square-peg))
```

When I run it I get:

```
insert-peg inserted with:  #direct_linking_test.core.SquarePeg{:width 5, :length 50}
```

Now I expect this to have *some* kind of indication that the type hint was wrong, but it doesn't.

Now I'm taking a look at the [Clojure Compiler code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java) - and I'm seeing the following hint handling code:

- [hinted arg list](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L7789)
- [emit static value from hinted fields](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L7929)
- [get the class of the hinted field](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L7974)
- [if hinted match method](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L8217)

But I'm not seeing the bit where it handles the type hint failure.

My question is: **Why doesn't the Clojure Compiler throw an error for an incorrect type hint?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type hints mostly[1] only affect code that would otherwise use reflection -- i.e., interop code.

Since your `insert-peg` function doesn't do any interop, there's no use for the type hint and it's ignored.

Type errors happen when your type hint caused the clojure compiler to write bytecode for calling the method of one type, but at runtime the instance turns out to be another type.

[1] see exception in Alex's comment below

Comment: quick demo of what you're saying about hints and errors user=> (.length ^String [1 2 3])
3
user=> (defn strlen [^String s] (.length s))
#'user/strlen
user=> (strlen [1 2 3])
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.lang.String  user/strlen (NO_SOURCE_FILE:4)

Comment: Type hints can also be used to create functions that take primitive numeric parameters without boxing, though that isn't relevant in this case.